# Built-in DSC resources not found

Tags: windows, powershell, dsc, powershell-5.0

How do I access the built-in DSC resources described here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn282121.aspx ?  They are supposed to be built-in, but I get an error when I try to use them in a configuration.

My configuration is as follows:

```
configuration Windows8VM
{
param
(
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [string] $ComputerName
)

Import-DSCResource -Name Package

Node $ComputerName
{
    File gitFolder
    {
        Ensure = "Present"
        Type = "Directory"
        DestinationPath = "C:\git"
    }

    Package gitSoftware
    {
        Ensure = "Present"
        Name = "git"
        ProductId = ''
        Path = https://chocolatey.org/api/v2/
        Arguments = '/SILENT /COMPONENTS="icons,ext\reg\shellhere,assoc,assoc_sh"'
    }
  }
}
```

The error I get is:

```
At C:\win8vmconfig.ps1:9 char:5
+     Import-DSCResource -Name Package
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Unable to load resource 'Package': Resource not found.
At C:\win8vmconfig.ps1:20 char:9
+         Package gitSoftware
+         ~~~~~~~
Undefined DSC resource 'Package'. Use Import-DSCResource to import the     resource.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DscResourcesNotFoundDuringParsing
```

So, it is completely incapable of locating the resource. What's going on here and what step am I missing to access the built-in DSC resources documented by Microsoft?

I'm using WMF/PowerShell 5.0.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `Import-DscResource` to use a built-in resource. That might actually be throwing it off. Do you still get the second error if you comment out that line?

Also you said you're using WMF 5. Could you clarify which operating system? As of this writing, only Windows 10 has a supported production ready version of PowerShell 5.

WMF 5 Production Preview is set to be released very soon, but for now any installable version is using experimental features.

Comment: I've tried this on two separate operating systems, Windows 7 and the newer Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter, so it seems OS independent.



I only added the `Import-DscResource` line in an attempt to resolve the original error,

Comment: @learningKnight Both Windows 7 and 2012 R2 can only be using DSC 5 with experimental features right now so it's possible that this is a bug. If you remove the `Import-DscResource` line, you get the original error then, which is the second error?

Comment: Correct, my comment got cut off there apparently,  but yes, the second error is the original one.

If I run `Get-DscResource`, only File shows up.  It seems like I'm missing an installation step, but I'm at a loss trying to figure out what I would need to install to gain access to these Resources.

Another odd thing is that the documentation resource I linked to in the original post is from 2013, so it raises an eyebrow to learn that these features are new to Window 10, but perhaps that has something to do with it, I'll see if I can get a Windows 10 machine set up...

Comment: @learningKnight the features are not new to Windows 10. All of the built in DSC resources were added in PowerShell 4 (the first version of DSC), which came out with 2012 R2, but there may be some changes to them. For example, in DSC 4, you could not use a NuGet package in a `Package` resource. To be honest, I'm still not sure if you can, but in any case it wouldn't cause the error you're seeing. Maybe try to reinstall WMF 5 if you can, or use a different release of it?

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help, it seems like my experience is atypical.  I'll set up a VM and do a fresh install WMF 5 (I'm using the latest release, which I believe is April 2015, but maybe I can try the Feb 2015 one instead).

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way to do this (although you version works and gives me a warning in the version of WMF 5 I'm running) is the example below.

Here is the warning I mentioned:

> WARNING: The configuration 'Windows8VM' is loading one or more built-in resources without explicitly importing associated modules.  Add Import-DscResource –ModuleName 'PSDesiredStateConfiguration' to your configuration to avoid this message.

```ps1
configuration Windows8VM
{
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [string] $ComputerName
    )

    Import-DSCResource -ModuleName PSDesiredStateConfiguration

    Node $ComputerName
    {
        File gitFolder
        {
            Ensure          = 'Present'
            Type            = 'Directory'
            DestinationPath = 'C:\git'
        }

        Package gitSoftware
        {
            Ensure    = 'Present'
            Name      = 'git'
            ProductId = ''
            Path      = 'https://chocolatey.org/api/v2/'
            Arguments = '/SILENT /COMPONENTS="icons,ext\reg\shellhere,assoc,assoc_sh"'
        }
    }
}
```